# git cloning in jenkins fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git

I couldn't clone the git repo in jenkins. The installed git version is 1.7.10. And also I configure the ssh key in the user directory. Using the same configuration, I could clone the git from command line and also in git bash.

But when I tried the same command from jenkins "Execute window batch command" the job failed with an error: `fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly`

```
C:\JenkinsSlave\workspace\ClonePath>git clone git@giturl.git 
Cloning into 'gitrepo'...
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: FAILURE
```

Comment: is there any relation to your previous two questions about git cloning in jenkins? If this is the same issue, you might want to change your first question and update the new insights, instead of making new questions. If this is a new problem, you might want to update your previous questions and explain how you fixed those problems.

Comment: Check your remote logs. This is usually an SSH public key authentication error of some kind.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9696902/git-clone-is-not-working-from-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your Jenkins job is running under the user account you think it is. But in any case cloning from the read only resource location is what you would do for most build servers. Try this instead:

```
git clone git://giturl.git
```